# Joomla. В ставка позиции для модуля

Tags: php, joomla

Joomla. Подскажите пожалуйста, как создать позицию для модуля или материала. Я не могу вписать фрагмент кода для создания позиции, т.к. в моём шаблоне в корне файл `index.php` не содержит других позиций для модулей. Где найти это код? Помогите, если можно и ссылку где почитать об изменении позиций.

Answer (score 0):

Код для объявления позиции для модулей можно подсмотреть в стандартных шаблонах, если они установлены. Если нет, то в документации: [Jdoc Statements=>Modules](https://docs.joomla.org/Jdoc_statements#Module). Вот пример для образца:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-3" style="themeHtml5" />
```

Comment: Спасибо. И всё таки где же находится код HTML, если в файле index.php находиться только PHP код?

Comment: Возможно, я не правильно понял ваш вопрос. К сожалению уточнение про HTML не внесло ясность. Возможно, речь идет о темплейтах которые используются в модулях для вывода информации. Там есть HTML код. Оператор jdoc обозначает место в index.php, в которое модули будут вставлять HTML. Для этого в панели администратора в разделе Extensions->Modules надо добавить или выбрать модуль, и назначить ему Position.

Comment: Кажется понял. index.php бывают разные. Тот, который в папке http - его изменять не нужно. Изменять нужно тот, который папке http\templates\\[template name]